# c# Web Server AJAX XMLHttpRequest Object

Tags: c#, xmlhttprequest

I have made a C# Socket Web Server, and I would like to add
AJAX to it

1. what code would be inside getdata.html
   to send a message back to the calling webpage?

Do need to install JavaScript Engine and if so how?

Thanks Inadvanced

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>The XMLHttpRequest Object</h1>

<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Request data</button>

<p id="demo"></p>


<script>
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "getdata.html", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The response to the AJAX request will be just whatever content is inside getdata.html. .html is just a static HTML file. It's unclear where C# fits into any of this? Are you actually hoping to make use of your C# program to receive the AJAX request, and return a response? In that case, the AJAX request needs to point to a valid URL in the C# webserver, such that the C# program receives the request, processes it, and returns a suitable response. Also it's unclear if you're using some flavour of ASP.NET here, or you somehow made your own custom webserver in C#?

Comment: Thanks for you Answer
I got it working, by got the server to read the URL
Then sending the information of sensor to the webpage
as a response

Comment: Oh there was a sensor involved? Not something you mentioned originally. Remember we're not mind-readers :-)